# Asymptote Angle rate of change for hyperbola

Tags: geometry

Assume there is a canonical hyperbola where the focus are $(c,0)$ and $(-c,0)$. The hyperbola curve intersects with the major axis at $(a,0)$ and $(-a,0)$. We can calculate $b^2 = c^2 - a^2$ so that the canonical hyperbola equation is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 $.
From this hyperbola we have the asymptote lines $y=\pm\frac{b}{a}x $.

Let us say that we have two data: $a$ and $a+\delta$. Each has its own asymptotes and there will be an angle between asymptote from $a$ and $a+\delta$. How to derive the equation for this angle as the function of $a$? And how to derive the angle rate of change with respect to $a$?

The value of $a$ is $0<a<c$. I know from Geogebra simulation (the figure below) that with bigger $a$ I will have bigger angle rate of change. But near $c$ this is no longer applies. I don't know how to explain it in mathematical formula. Thank you in advance.
[image: Asymptotes with the same \delta]

Comment: the matter is discussed in polar coordinates for hyperbola. There are a lot of web site that discuss it. But my purpose is to replace hyperbola with its asymptote for linearization. That is why I want to know the angle of its asymptote instead of hyperbola.

Comment: If I use Geogebra, let us say that $c=3$, the first $a=1$ and $a=1.1$, the second $a=2.4$ and $a=2.5$. You will see that with the same $\delta=0.1$ we will have different angle between two asymptotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given $a$ you have asymptotic lines
$$ y = \pm\frac ba x = \pm\frac{\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}}{a} x. $$

By symmetry, what happens to one line when you add $\delta$ to $a$
happens to the other line when you subtract $\delta$ from $a.$
So let's just consider one line; let's assume the $\pm$ sign is $+$.

The slope of the line is $b/a$ but the *angle* of the line (counterclockwise from the $x$ axis) is
$$ \theta(a) = \arctan\left(\frac ba\right)
 = \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}}{a}\right). $$

This function is discontinuous at $a = 0$ (undefined at $a = 0$ exactly, and it jumps from an angle near $\frac\pi2$ (a right angle) to an angle near $-\frac\pi2$ as $a$ goes from a small positive value to a small negative value).
You could define the function differently for $a<0$ and add a definition of $\theta(0)$ to make a continuous function with output between $0$ and $\pi,$
but perhaps you would be satisfied just to consider $a > 0$ and not be concerned about what happens as we cross over from positive to negative $a$.

If you're looking for the difference in angle when you add a particular $\delta$ to $a,$ it's

$$ \left\lvert \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{c^2 - (a+\delta)^2}}{a+\delta}\right)
 - \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}}{a}\right) \right\rvert. $$

Not a nice expression, though it might be possible to get a reasonable small-$\delta$ approximation with Taylor series.

If you mean the *instantaneous* rate of change of the angle when you refer to
"angle rate of change", then you're asking about

$$ \theta'(a) = 
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da} \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}}{a}\right).$$

For the line with slope $\frac ba$ this value is always negative,
that is, the line rotates clockwise as $a$ increases.
As your Geogebra graphs hint, the rate of change becomes more negative
(hence larger in magnitude) as $a$ gets closer to $c.$
The magnitude of the rate of change grows without bound as $a$ gets close to $c.$